# When submit a form using PHP_SELF ,To which URL it will redirect ( MVC)?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

In my application I have `localhost/controller/action` (MVC).   I open a page `localhost/user/register` .  and i have a form their .    And surprisingly when i submit form using `<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER[PHP_SELF];?>" >` Then form submission redirects me to `localhost/index.php` i want to redirect it to the same url `localhost/user/register` when i submit a form how can i achieve this

Comment: Dont use ,htaccess for parsing "pretty urls". Instead do it on PHP side.

Comment: @tereško  I am doing it on localhost,  can you please explain little more how to use php for redirect urls in MVC(and some usefull MVC tips for begginers). you are expert in mvc. thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Leave the action attribute of the form empty.

```
<form method="post"></form>
```

It will submit in the current URL.